# date format to string

Tags: string, date, excel, casting, vba

I have created this sub with the intention of taking the Default American Date Convention, Changing it to a British format "yyyy-mm-dd" and then casting to a string. I want to change the format before converting to a string because it is easier to work with for my purpose.  However, the string appears to be preserved in the original American format although the cell format has been changed.  How can I solve this and what is reason it is doing this?

```
Sub Changedate()

    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 4).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"

    Dim firstDate As String
    Dim secondDate As String

    firstDate = Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Value)
    secondDate = Str(Sheet1.Cells(1, 4).Value)

    MsgBox firstDate

    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 4).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is a typical value you actually **see** in a cell.......the "as-formatted" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:
    `firstDate = format(Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")`
Excel date is just a number and changing NumberFormat only affects how it is displayed.
Str() probably uses your system default date format, you must use Format() to force it.

Comment: doesnt seem to work. I tried this and I'm getting a compile error... it **should** work (I look in the vba help files and copied and pasted their example for format) but the error says "expected array"

Comment: the code I posted works for me could you post exact value from sheet (as Gary asked)?

Comment: not actually my question, I just tested it before posting my answer because if it worked i wasnt gonna bother. its a compile error im getting so actually nothing to do with the value in the cell. although the "actual" value in the cell I set it for is `09/03/2010
`

Comment: i have excel 2010, what do you have? maybe its a newer/older version thing

Comment: apologies your code works fine im just having a "stupid" day. I made a string variable called "format" so when i was trying to call the method it was trying to do something with my variable instead of the method.

Answer (score 1):

what you can also try is to use the `.text` property instead of `.value`.  `.value` gets the cells contents without formatting. so you may see the string formatted incorrectly using `.value`. `.text` gets the cell contents **with** formatting (watch the run time, if this is running in a loop is may start to take a long time.) `.text` is the slowest method for getting cell contents, though with only a few rows or runs it wont make much difference